# Conditional Custom Text Filter plugin

Tags: 8

I have created a custom text filter plugin by extending `FilterBase` class. The `process()` function looks like

```
 public function process($text, $langcode) {
    // Get the current node to determine if it has the glossary field and if
    // that field is enabled.
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node && $node->hasField('field_glossary') && $node->field_glossary->value) {

      // Get all the terms in the Glossary vocabulary.
      $terms = $this->getTerms('glossary');

      // Make all the replacements.
      $new_text = $this->doReplace($text, $terms);

      // Create a filtered text object with the updated text.
      $result = new FilterProcessResult($new_text);
      return $result;
    }
    else {
      // Don't do the replacement.
      $result = new FilterProcessResult($text);
      return $result;
    }
  }
```

I am letting editor to choose to turn off/on text filtering via plugin by creating a flag field as used in code `$node->field_glossary->value`. The problem comes when I need to check the field value on non-node page, as on node page I can get the node object and check the value but for other entites like blocks how can I get the source entity for text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not so easy, because the filter is normally not aware from which field it is called from.

The token filter module does this trick:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function token_filter_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['element']['#object']) && $variables['element']['#object'] instanceof ContentEntityInterface) {
    $entity = &drupal_static('token_filter_entity');
    $entity = $variables['element']['#object'];
  }
}
```

The parent entity of the field is stored in a static variable and can be used in the filter:

```
  public function process($text, $langcode) {
    $entity = drupal_static('token_filter_entity', NULL);
    if (!is_null($entity) && $entity instanceof ContentEntityInterface) {
      // use entity
    }
  }
```

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/token_filter/tree/token_filter.module?h=8.x-1.x

This may not be the best solution for most cases. If possible look for a better place for the code where you have direct access to the entity. For example in [hook_entity_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/8.2.x).